Lib XLSX em javascript, exporta para planilha valor do tipo Data
Estou utilizando a lib XLSX, ao exportar para o excel ela vem no formato texto, e se eu forçar para o tipo Data, ela vem com a data do dia anterior e com horario.
Estou a horas tentando de alguma forma fazer a data ir para o excel no tipo dd/mm/yyyy.
Com o codigo abaixo eu efetuo forçando o tipo do campo para data, dessa forma a planilha consegue formatar para o tipo data. Porem no momento ela vai dessa forma para o excel dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss, porem preciso apenas do tipo dd/mm/yyyy.
A documentação não é clara de como efetuar isso.
const worksheet = utils.json_to_sheet(rows)
    
     for (let i = 2; i <= tableInstance.getCoreRowModel().rows.length + 1; i++) {
        const cellRef = `H${i}`; // Supondo que a coluna B contém as datas
        if (worksheet[cellRef]) {
          // Define a célula como do tipo data
          worksheet[cellRef].t = 'd'; // 'd' para data
        }
      }
    const workbook = utils.book_new()

    utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Titulos')

    const currentDate = new Date();
    const day = currentDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const month = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const year = currentDate.getFullYear().toString();
    const currentDateFormated =  day + month + year;

    writeFile(workbook, `data_${currentDateFormated}.xlsx`)

Caso algo não ficou claro favor me informar para que eu possa melhorar a pergunta, estou a precisar dessa ajuda.

Você já não perguntou isso aqui, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/597756?

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
